Announce ULA route to Cisco switches via SLAAC
I have trouble with Cisco switches (specifically the CBS350 series if that matters) and local IPv6 routing. I run an x86 OpenWrt as router. Its ULA prefix is fd8e:3a8c:273b::/48 which is distributed as multiple /64 prefixes to downstream interfaces. The router's DHCP configurations for its management interface are as follow:
config dhcp 'management'
    option interface 'management'
    option dhcpv4 'server'
    option start '112'
    option limit '15'
    option ra 'server' # enable Router Advertisement
    option ra_slaac '1' # announce SLAAC for a prefix (that is, set the A flag in RA messages)
    list ra_flags 'none' # set neither M flag nor O flag
    option ra_dns '1' # RFC 8106
    option dhcpv6 'disabled' # disables DHCPv6 server on this interface to use SLAAC exclusively

I plugged a Windows PC into this subnet, and it can receive the ULA route fd8e:3a8c:273b::/48 just fine:
Active Routes:
If  Metric  Network Destination                         Gateway
1   331     ::1/128                                     On-link
19  356     fd8e:3a8c:273b::/48                         fe80::f292:1cff:fe5b:208b
19  356     fd8e:3a8c:273b:80::/64                      On-link
19  356     fd8e:3a8c:273b:80:90:e5cb:a7cb:a2ab/128     On-link
19  356     fd8e:3a8c:273b:80:ee0d:20ae:6531:b8ae/128   On-link
19  356     fe80::/64                                   On-link
19  356     fe80::ef0d:f73b:2b:a5f2/128                 On-link
1   331     ff00::/8                                    On-link
19  356     ff00::/8                                    On-link

On the Cisco switch, I use the following commands:
cisco(config)#interface vlan 1
cisco(config-if)#ipv6 address autoconfig # 'autoconfig' means SLAAC while 'dhcp' means DHCPv6

I do not know why it could not receive (or autoconfigure) the ULA route:
cisco#show ipv6 route

Codes: > - Best
            I - ICMP Redirect, S - Static, C - Connected,
            ND - Router Advertisement
[d/m]: d - route's distance, m - route's metric

IPv6 Forwarding is disabled

IPv6 Routing Table - 1 entries

 ND> fd8e:3a8c:273b:80::/64 [0/0]
        via :: VLAN 1

I tried to set a static route to the ULA subnet and it failed:
cisco(config)#ipv6 route fd8e:3a8c:273b::/48 fd8e:3a8c:273b:1::1 # this the the router IPv6 address
IPv6 nexthop address fd8e:3a8c:273b:1::1 is not valid

I had to use the link-local address of the router management interface (fe80::f292:1cff:fe5b:208b) to get it done:
cisco(config)#ipv6 route fd8e:3a8c:273b::/48 fe80::f292:1cff:fe5b:208b%vlan1 vlan1 1
cisco(config)#exit
cisco#show ipv6 route

Codes: > - Best
            I - ICMP Redirect, S - Static, C - Connected,
            ND - Router Advertisement
[d/m]: d - route's distance, m - route's metric

IPv6 Forwarding is disabled

IPv6 Routing Table - 2 entries

    S> fd8e:3a8c:273b::/48 [1/1]
        via fe80::f292:1cff:fe5b:208b VLAN 1
    ND> fd8e:3a8c:273b:80::/64 [0/0]
        via :: VLAN 1

Can someone help me understand why the Cisco switch did not receive a ULA route to subnet fd8e:3a8c:273b::/48 (while the Windows PC did), and why setting a static route using the router address fd8e:3a8c:273b:1::1 failed?
P.S: I just found that my CCTV cameras behave the same way as the Cisco did: they can autoconfigure their IPv6 addresses using the advertised prefix and EUI-64. No route to the /48 subnet was auto-configured though, hence they could not be reached from other local subnets. I suspect they lack support for some sort of IPv6 standard.

First, your OpenWrt router is off-topic here.
You have not enabled IPv6 routing on the switches, so they are layer-2 devices that only know about the directly connected network. You can enable a default gateway that is on the same network, and all switch management interface traffic destined off that network will be sent to the default gateway. You can configure a default gateway on a layer-2 switch (it is only for the switch management interface, not for switching).
To configure routes on a switch, it must be a layer-3 switch, and you must then enable IPv6 routing on it. I believe the 300 series is capable of routing, but you have not enabled it: "IPv6 Forwarding is disabled" is in your post.
If you only want to use it as a layer-2 switch, then just set the default gateway to the router address in that network. You do not need that except to reach the switch management interface from other networks. The switch will switch at layer-2 with no problems.

The switch is working at layer 2 only. I know that I have not enabled the IPv6 default gateway, and it is intended to be so. The default gateway should be configured when the OpenWrt router connects to the Internet and gets a GUA prefix. I have taken a look at the IPv6 routing table again and see that the local route fd8e:3a8c:273b:80::/64 [0/0] via :: VLAN 1 should be label C meaning "directly connected" instead of ND which means "received via Router Advertisement". While the route to the /48 ULA is advertised by RA but not configured. I think this is a bug of this switch firmware.

That is not a bug. A layer-2 switch does not need any routes, except for its management interface, and then only a default route, meaning any traffic destined off-net is through the default gateway.

After the OpenWrt get the IPv6 prefix delegation from the ISP, it will further delegate downstream to the Cisco switch. The Cisco switch will auto-config the default gateway (GUA) using SLAAC. I do not want to configure the ULA of the OpenWrt router as the default gateway -- I want only a route to the ULA prefix.
My computer is in a different subnet and I always use ULA to manage the Cisco switch. There is no point connecting to it using GUA. I just don't know why the Cisco does not configure the route received from Router Advertisement hence forces me configure it manually.

Again, layer-2 switches do not route. I do not care how you want it to work. Routing is at layer-3. You do not configure routes on a layer-2 switch. You should never use DHCP or SLAAC to configure network devices; you always statically configure the addresses of network devices. Remember that IPv6 uses the link-local address of the router as the gateway. It is not like IPv4. Get out of IPv4-thinking when it comes to IPv6.
